# Is there any support for transactions in JCR / Jackrabbit?

Tags: aem, jcr, jackrabbit

In the following case,

```
Session s = getJcrSessionWithSimpleCredentials();
Node parent = getSomeNode(s).;
parent.addNode("firstChild","nt:unstructured");
parent.addNode("second/child","nt:unstructured");
s.save();
```

The first child will be saved, but second child will throw `RepositoryExcepion`, as there is slash "/" in the node name. 
Now I want to rollback my changes of creating both nodes.

How this can be handled in JCR / Jacrabbit ?

Comment: There's nothing you need to roll back. The "save" operation does not create the first node.

Comment: I tested it again, the first node get's saved but second node doesn't. One correction exception is "PathNotFoundException" for "child" as parent path is missing till "somenode/second" is not present.

Well, but my intention is any error in creating node should rollback all changes.

Comment: That's not supposed to happen. How did you test that the first node was saved?

Answer (score 2):

```
Session s = getJcrSessionWithSimpleCredentials();
Node parent = getSomeNode(s).;
parent.addNode("firstChild","nt:unstructured");
parent.addNode("second/child","nt:unstructured");
s.save();
```

If, as you say, the line `parent.addNode("second/child","nt:unstructured")` throws an exception, `s.save()` is not executed (the line is never reached) and others will not see the changes you made to the repository.

In your session, however, the addition of `firstChild` is still going to be visible.

You can refresh the session to give up the changes local to your session. As a short example:

```
try {
    Session s = getJcrSessionWithSimpleCredentials();
    Node parent = getSomeNode(s).;
    parent.addNode("firstChild","nt:unstructured");
    parent.addNode("second/child","nt:unstructured");
    s.save();
} catch (PathNotFoundException ex) {
    // log the exception
    // give up all unsaved changes made in your session
    s.refresh(false); 
}
```

Please mind that this is just meant as a concise example. Personally, I'd *check for the existence of the parent before attempting to save the node rather than catch `PathNotFoundException`*. The point is, you can execute a session refresh when you want to give up the unsaved changes. Be it in a catch block or a branch of a conditional expression.

To quote the [Javadoc for `Session#refresh(boolean keepChanges)`](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/spec/javax.jcr/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Session.html#refresh(boolean))

> If `keepChanges` is false, this method discards all pending changes currently recorded in this `Session` and returns all items to reflect the current saved state. Outside a transaction this state is simply the current state of persistent storage. Within a transaction, this state will reflect persistent storage as modified by changes that have been saved but not yet committed.

As for transaction support, you can read more [here](https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/spec/jcr/2.0/21_Transactions.html).